# "Run" option in Raspbian menu

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie

When I access the Raspbian menu, I see an option called "Run":

[image: The Run option]

What does this option do and how can I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's for running programs or commands.  For example, try entering:

```
leafpad
```

which is the text editor, and the text editor will open (Run).